# Reshaping from Wide to Long using Year in Variable Name

Tags: r, panel, reshape

I am trying to reshape a large dataframe (34645 x 11619) from wide to long. I would like to reshape the years 99 to 16. This means I have variables such as "edu**99**", "edu**00**", ... "edu**16**" or variables such as "p99d**61**", "p**00**d61", ..., "p**16**d61". The year string is not always on the same position.

Is there a way, to tell R to look for the the year strings "99-16" in the variable names when reshaping? (of course given that the string numbers uniquely identify the year).

Or in general, are there efficient strategy to reshape a big dataset?

Thank you so much for your help!

Best, Patrick

Comment: To better receive effective answers, please 1) show your codes; 2) provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **tidyr** instead of **reshape** for this one:

1. wide to long using `gather()` function: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html
2. extract the year using `extract()` function: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html

You can use this regex for step 2 to extract the year `"(99|0[0-9]|1[1-9])"`. It selects any digits-pair equal to 99, between 00 and 09 or between 10 and 19.

`extract(<long_data_name>, <column_name>, <string_name_of_result_column>, regex = "(99|0[0-9]|1[1-9])", remove = TRUE)`